Laravel 10 Cookie::forget() Not Working while PHP setcookie code working fine
I am trying to remove cookie from a function whenever it is success. Here is the code
    // Removing coupon from cookies & session
    if($coupon){
        Cookie::queue(Cookie::forget('automatic-coupon','/'));
        session()->forget('automatic-coupon');
    }

But I have no luck. The session is working fine but not the cookie itself. It is not removed. Am I missing something?
Meanwhile when I use a simple php code like
setcookie('automatic-coupon',null,0,'/');

It is working, can anyone help me? I wanna use laravel instead of pure php code itself. Thank you
